# http app consume https web api - is it secure?

Tags: api, http, https

I have an old web app that uses HTTP, and I am building a web API the old app will utilize. The API uses HTTPS. When the app consumes the Web API, will the connection be secure?

Comment: No, and not only that, but you'll also very like have CORS issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into CORS